# Как узнать индекс рандомного значения которое определено в head_check

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

```
def Head(self):
    # Здесь все возможные лбы Исторических людей
    global head
    head = []
    head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head0.png'))
    head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head1.png'))
    head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head2.png'))
    head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head3.png'))
    head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head4.png'))
    head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head5.png'))
    head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head6.png'))
    head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head7.png'))
    head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head8.png'))
    head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head9.png'))
    global head_check
    head_check = random.choice(head)
    self.ui.head.setPixmap(head_check)
```

Comment: Как узнать индекс элемента который был рандомно определён в head_check

Comment: а причем тут `PyQt`?

Comment: Потому, что программа пишется на PyQT, ну может быть зря поставил, надо было только Python оставить

Comment: обычной функцией определения индекса в массиве можно `head.index(head_check)`

Comment: Twiss, Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2):

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        ...

        # Здесь все возможные лбы Исторических людей
        self.heads = [
            QPixmap('images\head\head0.png'),
            QPixmap('images\head\head1.png'),
            QPixmap('images\head\head2.png'),
            QPixmap('images\head\head3.png'),
            QPixmap('images\head\head4.png'),
            ...
            QPixmap('images\head\head9.png'),
        ]

        ...

    def Head(self):
        head_check = random.choice(self.heads)
        self.ui.head.setPixmap(head_check)
        
        index = self.heads.index(head_check)  # Индекс
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'QLabel' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: у меня в ответе `self.heads.` -- список, у вас -- QLabel. Вы у `self.ui.head.index` вызывали?

Comment: Ответ нашёл выше, спасибо.

Comment: Эмм, мой ответ такой же как и выше, да и раньше его написал :) [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: это все охота на репутацию :DD